# Translate buttons inside JQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have this datatable:
[image]

As you can see, there are 2 buttons for each row, brought to life like this:

```
columns:[  
   {  
      data:"numPoliza"
   },
   {  
      data:"primaAnual",
      render:$.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.',0,'',' €')
   },
   {  
      data:"producto"
   },
   {  
      data:"mediador"
   },
   {  
      data:"fechaEfecto",
      "render":function(data){  
         var locale = $locale.id; 
         return (moment(data).isValid()) ? moment(data).locale(locale).format("L"):"-"         ;
      }
   },
   {  
      data:"estado"
   },
   {  
      data:"varPlan",
      "defaultContent":"<a href='' class='btn btn-default' style='width: 100%'><i>Ver condiciones</i></a>"
   },
   {  
      data:null,
      "defaultContent":"<a href='' class='btn btn-default' style='width: 100%'><i>Ver detalles</i></a>"
   }
]
```

Now, what I want to do is to translate this buttons to the 3 available languages in our webapp (Spanish, Portuguese and English). I have tried to pass a "data-translate='XXX'" parameter, with no luck. Also I have tried to modify the language atribute, no go either.

AFAIK there is an [i18n option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.text) inside Datatables to achieve this, but the example provided does not fit my buttons, as they are created in a HTML fashion.

Could you please help me? Thanks :)

--PROGRESS REPORT--

As I have been researching, the use of [columns.render()](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) (and not defaultContent) is key here. I'm trying to return a function based on the present locale, but I'm not sure how the render function works.

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: You need to do this yourself by using variables instead of hard code text

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, thanks for your help. I'm quite new to Datatables, could you elaborate on your comment/answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, not the classiest way of doing it for sure, but will have to do until we perform some optimizations. For the sake of helpfulness, this is what I did:

```
{  
   data:"varPlan",
   "orderable":false,
   "searchable":false,
   "render":function(){  
      var locale = $locale.id; 
      if (locale === 'es'){  
         return "<a href='' id='terms' class='btn btn-default' style='width:100%'><i>Ver condiciones</i></a>"
      }else if (locale === 'pt-pt')      {  
         return "<a href='' id='terms' class='btn btn-default' style='width:100%'><i>Ver condições</i></a>"
      }else{  
         return "<a href='' id='terms' class='btn btn-default' style='width:100%'><i>Show terms</i></a>"
      }
   }
}
```

- Replaced defaultContent (which, as the name states, only serves as an static value AFAIK).
- Used a function with "render" property, which returns the button with different HTML value depending on the active locale.
- Rinse and repeat.